# loop through two lists of lists and extract elements

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have two lists:

list_a contains the number of questions and types I want. There are three types 1* 2* 3*

list_b contain all the questions and the types eg 'Q1:1*' and 'Q1 is of type 1*' is considered one question..

So far I have managed to write a code that loops through and randomly selects the number of questions and the type I want.

```
import random

list_a = [[1, 1, 1]] # Read this as i want 1 question of type 1*, 
                       1 question of type 2* and 1 question of type 3*

list_b = [['Q1:1*','Q1 is of type 1*', 'Q2:1*', 'Q2 is of type 1*', 'Q3:2*', 'Q3 is of type 2*', 
           'Q4:2*','Q4 is of type 2*', 'Q5:3*', 'Q5 is of type 3*', 'Q6:3*', 'Q6 is of type 3*']]

result = []

# Iterate over each type of question in list_a
for i in range(len(list_a[0])):
    # Determine the number of questions required for this type
    num_questions = list_a[0][i]

    # Create a list of the indices of questions in list_b that match this type
    question_indices = [idx for idx, q in enumerate(list_b[0]) if f":{i+1}*" in q]

    # Randomly select the required number of questions and their corresponding elements
    selected_indices = random.sample(question_indices, num_questions)
    selected_questions = [list_b[0][idx] for idx in selected_indices]
    selected_elements = [list_b[0][idx+1] for idx in selected_indices]

    # Append the selected questions and elements to the result list
    for q, e in zip(selected_questions, selected_elements):
        result.append(q)
        result.append(e)

# Print the final result
print(result)
```

I get the following results.

```
['Q2:1*', 'Q2 is of type 1*', 'Q3:2*', 'Q3 is of type 2*', 'Q6:3*', 'Q6 is of type 3*']
```

Everything works fine, except I want to make this code more dynamic. i.e

I want to modify the code such that it allows my  list_a & list_b to be a list of lists eg

`list_a = [[1,1,1],[1,2,1]]`

```
list_b = [['Q1:1*','Q1 is of type 1*', 'Q2:1*', 'Q2 is of type 1*', 'Q3:2*', 'Q3 is of type 2*', 
           'Q4:2*','Q4 is of type 2*', 'Q5:3*', 'Q5 is of type 3*', 'Q6:3*', 'Q6 is of type 3*'],['Q7:1*','Q7 is of type 1*', 'Q8:1*', 'Q8 is of type 1*', 'Q9:2*', 'Q9 is of type 2*', 'Q10:2*','Q10 is of type 2*', 'Q11:3*', 'Q11 is of type 3*', 'Q12:3*', 'Q12 is of type 3*']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the list to go through each sublist, currently, you are only using the first sublist from each list.

The code for it can be like this,

```
import random

list_a = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]  # read as: 1st sublist wants 1 question of type 1*, 1 question of type 2*, and 1 question of type 3*; 2nd sublist wants 1 question of type 1*, 2 questions of type 2*, and 1 question of type 3*
list_b = [['Q1:1*', 'Q1 is of type 1*', 'Q2:1*', 'Q2 is of type 1*', 'Q3:2*', 'Q3 is of type 2*', 'Q4:2*', 'Q4 is of type 2*', 'Q5:3*', 'Q5 is of type 3*', 'Q6:3*', 'Q6 is of type 3*'], ['Q7:1*', 'Q7 is of type 1*', 'Q8:1*', 'Q8 is of type 1*', 'Q9:2*', 'Q9 is of type 2*', 'Q10:2*', 'Q10 is of type 2*', 'Q11:3*', 'Q11 is of type 3*', 'Q12:3*', 'Q12 is of type 3*']]

result = []

# Iterate over each sublist in list_a and list_b
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    sublist_a = list_a[i]
    sublist_b = list_b[i]

    # Iterate over each type of question in sublist_a
    for j in range(len(sublist_a)):
        # Determine the number of questions required for this type
        num_questions = sublist_a[j]

        # Create a list of the indices of questions in sublist_b that match this type
        question_indices = [idx for idx, q in enumerate(sublist_b) if f":{j+1}*" in q]

        # Randomly select the required number of questions and their corresponding elements
        selected_indices = random.sample(question_indices, num_questions)
        selected_questions = [sublist_b[idx] for idx in selected_indices]
        selected_elements = [sublist_b[idx+1] for idx in selected_indices]

        # Append the selected questions and elements to the result list
        for q, e in zip(selected_questions, selected_elements):
            result.append(q)
            result.append(e)

# Print the final result
print(result)
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, if its not too much trouble is it possible to modify it further such that if ` list_a=[0,0,0,5] ` introducing the 4th element simply means to randomly select any question type. This only works for if the first three elements are 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension, where i've included a new element (4th) where by it selects random type questions if the first 3 are all 0s.

@gaurav, if you have a cleaner/simpler way of doing this that would be great!

```
list_a = [[1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3]]  # read as: 1st sublist wants 1 question of type 1*, 1 question of type 2*, and 1 question of type 3*; 2nd sublist wants 3 questions randomly selected from the available question types if there are any
list_b = [['Q1:1*', 'Q1 is of type 1*', 'Q2:1*', 'Q2 is of type 1*', 'Q3:2*', 'Q3 is of type 2*', 'Q4:2*', 'Q4 is of type 2*',
           'Q5:3*', 'Q5 is of type 3*', 'Q6:3*', 'Q6 is of type 3*'], ['Q7:1*', 'Q7 is of type 1*', 'Q8:1*', 'Q8 is of type 1*',
            'Q9:2*', 'Q9 is of type 2*', 'Q10:2*', 'Q10 is of type 2*', 'Q11:3*', 'Q11 is of type 3*', 'Q12:3*', 'Q12 is of type 3*']]

result = []

# Iterate over each sublist in list_a and list_b
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    sublist_a = list_a[i]
    sublist_b = list_b[i]

    # Check if the last element is greater than 0 and the first three elements are equal to 0
    if sublist_a[-1] > 0 and sublist_a[:3] == [0, 0, 0]:
        # Create a list of the indices of questions in sublist_b that match any type
        question_indices = [idx for idx, q in enumerate(sublist_b) if ":1*" in q or ":2*" in q or ":3*" in q]

        # Randomly select the required number of questions and their corresponding elements
        selected_indices = random.sample(question_indices, sublist_a[-1])
        selected_questions = [sublist_b[idx] for idx in selected_indices]
        selected_elements = [sublist_b[idx+1] for idx in selected_indices]

        # Append the selected questions and elements to the result list
        for q, e in zip(selected_questions, selected_elements):
            result.append(q)
            result.append(e)

    # Otherwise, iterate over each type of question in sublist_a
    else:
        for j in range(len(sublist_a)-1):
            # Determine the number of questions required for this type
            num_questions = sublist_a[j]

            # Create a list of the indices of questions in sublist_b that match this type
            question_indices = [idx for idx, q in enumerate(sublist_b) if f":{j+1}*" in q]

            # Randomly select the required number of questions and their corresponding elements
            selected_indices = random.sample(question_indices, num_questions)
            selected_questions = [sublist_b[idx] for idx in selected_indices]
            selected_elements = [sublist_b[idx+1] for idx in selected_indices]

            # Append the selected questions and elements to the result list
            for q, e in zip(selected_questions, selected_elements):
                result.append(q)
                result.append(e)

# Print the final result
print(result)
```